# upload image and encode face with opencv and face_recognition

Tags: python, django, sqlite, opencv, face-recognition

I want to take the photo file selected in the form using opencv and encode the face using face_recognition in Django before my information is saved in the database. But I can't get the photo file from cleaned data. please Help me

---

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import View
from .models import ImageEncode
from .forms import CreateEncodeImage
from django.contrib import messages
import cv2, os
import face_recognition
from django.conf import settings

class AddCustomFaceView(View):
    form_class = CreateEncodeImage
    path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'face_lib/')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class
        return render(request, 'home/custom-face.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_face = form.save(commit=False)

            img_name = form.cleaned_data['imgname']
            img_add = form.cleaned_data['imgaddress']

            img_face = cv2.imread(f'{img_add}')
            img_face = cv2.cvtColor(img_face, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            face_loc = face_recognition.face_locations(img_face)
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = face_loc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1, x2, y2, x1
            image_frame = img_face[y1:y2, x1:x2]
            encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_face)

            if encode:
                new_face.imgencode = encode[0]
                new_face.imgname = img_name
                new_face.imgaddress = form.cleaned_data('imgaddress')
                new_face.save()
                cv2.imwrite(self.path + img_name, image_frame)
                messages.success(request, 'New Custom Face Saved', 'success')
            else:
                messages.warning(request, 'could not save this face', 'success')
                return redirect('home:face_custom')
            return redirect('home:list_img')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, 'not valid data', 'warning')
            return redirect('home:face_custom')
```

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import ImageEncode

class CreateEncodeImage(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ImageEncode
        fields = ('imgname', 'imgaddress',)
```

my models.py

```
import numpy as np
from django.db import models
from ndarraydjango.fields import NDArrayField

class ImageEncode(models.Model):
    imgencode = NDArrayField(shape=(32, 4), dtype=np.float64)
    imgname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    imgaddress = models.ImageField(upload_to='face_lib/', null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/file-uploads/